# Android Studio Unsatisfied linkerror while trying to open.so file

Tags: android-studio, abi, dlopen, unsatisfiedlinkerror, .so

Android Studio 4.0 is installed on my Windows 10 (64-bit) system.

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qs5501demo.aidl"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

on clicking run app button, I got the following error:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.qs5501demo.aidl, PID: 4368
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/~~U7rD8N9mzMhsX2x4MALzmg==/com.qs5501demo.aidl-fQAI7kmWEWiITYxrOd-qQQ==/lib/arm/libzyapi_common.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
at android.zyapi.CommonApi.(CommonApi.java:26)
at com.qs.wiget.App.openGPIO(App.java:372)
at com.qs.wiget.App.init(App.java:101)
at com.qs.wiget.App.onCreate(App.java:93)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6607)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:233)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1896)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)

the erro is with libzyapi_common.so file which is in the folder ~\app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi. Also there is a jar file in ~\app\libs named core.jar. Please someone help me to check if this jar and so files are placed in the correct folders.

Comment: Upon running _what_? AS itself, or some program you were trying to build? If the latter, show the build setup, libraries used, library settings, etc.

Comment: It would surely be helpful to include some info on this project, such as what libraries it tries to load and how.